# ssmtp not working with outlook account

Tags: ssmtp

I have been trying to send emails with ssmtp through my outlook account.
I followed this page and this is what I have inside ssmtp.conf:

```
root=myemail@outlook.com
mailhub=smtp-mail.outlook.com:587
AuthUser=myemail@outlook.com
AuthPass=mypassword
UseTLS=YES
UseSTARTTLS=YES
rewriteDomain=outlook.com
hostname=myemail@outlook.com
FromLineOverride=YES
```

But when I want o test ssmtp, like by typing this in the terminal:

```
ssmtp destination@gmail.com
```

nothing happens, and the terminal freezes. Any clue where I can start debugging this?

Comment: I presume the terminal isn't frozen but `ssmtp` awaits your input (mail content) in its stdin. Type a few words and hit CTRL-D to end your message.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. It was not frozen, but I still could not send emails. I switched to postfix and it seems to be working now.

Comment: I had the same problem:
You can't use myemail@outlook.com as hostname.
Use myemail or localhost instead.
But now I receive the mails, but void mail, without text and void attachments.

Comment: @SaTa, would you please teach me how to config postfix to login outlook? I am using ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

After couple of trials, I have realized that there are two ways to use this command.

### Email from file

```
sendmail username@example.com < file.txt
```

### Echoing text

```
echo -e "Subject:<SUBJECT> \n\n <BODY>\n" | sendmail username@example.com
```